# Change color of of menu drawer hamburger icon in Android

Tags: android, colors

I would like to change the icon color from of the hamburger icon. I tried a lots things and nothing worked. Here my **XML**:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
 android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
 app:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
 app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"
 android:elevation="4dp"/>
```

In **styles.xml** I have

```xml
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using AppCompat. Please create this or similar style:

```
<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">#D81B60</item>
</style>
```

Then use it in your theme:

```
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
```

Comment: i dont know why when i change the line in the theme, when i debug, it change alone to the other line and it remove the new one, why?

Comment: not sure I understand your follow up, sorry. what I'm sure about is the answer works, as I test before I post :)